# Prove that sub-trees have a common vertex

Tags: graph-theory

OK so this is a bonus question I got that I would really like to solve because I have been sitting on it for an hour without any progress. Any direction from you guys would be very helpful:

Let $T$ be a tree with $n$ vertices, and let $T_1,T_2,...,T_k$ be sub-trees of $T$. So $T_i=(V_i,E_i)$ for every $1\le i\le k$.
Also, for every $1\le i\lt j\le k$, let's suppose that  $V_i\cap V_j\neq\emptyset$.
Prove that $\bigcap_{i=1}^kV_i \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson Oh whoops I was reading $\ne$ as $=$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Prove the slightly stronger result that $\bigcap T_i$ is a subtree of $T$. This can be proved by induction on $k$.

Comment: I think I'm I'm missing something, let me know where I'm wrong:
Base: Let's take a stronger base then $k=1$, say $k=2$. We have two subtrees $T_1,T_2$. Let's look at $T_1\cap T_2$. 
Connectivity: Take any two vertices $u,v$ - they are both in $T_1$ so they are connected. No cycles: obvious. So $T_1\cap T_2$ is a subtree. Then if we persume for $k$, the next step for $k+1$ is exactly like the base case. 

Does that prove the original claim? I can't seem to see the connection.. maybe it's the lack of sleep :/

Comment: I mean, you should certainly flesh out the things you've said a little... but yes, you've got the right idea! And yes, the inductive step is almost exactly the same; just observe that the intersection of the first $k$ is a subtree. You just have one thing missing: why should that subtree have a nontrivial intersection with the $(k+1)$st tree?

Comment: That's indeed a good question :). I know that each $V_i\cap V_j\neq\emptyset$, but I don't see why they couldn't all be intersected in different vertices, in which case there won't be a definite intersection of $T_1\cap T_2\cap ...\cap T_k$ with $T_{k+1}$. I know that for every $T_i\cap T_j\neq\emptyset$, but when we intersect many trees I don't see why the next one also has an intersection, since we now have a subtree that is different than any of the former trees. This is exactly why I can't get the original claim - just substitute trees with $V_i$..

Comment: OK so I came up with something in the shower, probably wrong:
Take the first two $V_1\cap V_2$. It's not empty, let's call such a vertex $r$ for root. I think we can prove that this $r$ exists in every $V_i$. Let's assume (for contradiction) that $r\notin V_3$. So there exists $v_{13}\in V_1$ and also $v_{13}\in V_3$. Similarily, there exists $v_{23}\in V_2$ and also $v_{23}\in V_3$. But if both $V_{13},V_{23}\neq r$, then we have a path that goes $<r...V_{13}...V_{23}...r>$ meaning it's a circle. Contradiction? If so, we proved that there must be an $r$ that belongs to all $V_i$.

Comment: Absolutely right!  And, in fact, a better solution than I was getting at.

Comment: Thanks! Finally I can go to sleep :)